# Doubt trying to understand the product in category theory?

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading Walters' Categories and Computer Science, here we have the definition of product:

> [image]

I made a Mathematica code just to "see the definition working" but am confused with the following issue:

- I defined my objects as elements of $A=\{\{\},\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$.
- I defined my arrows as $a\to b$ if $a \subset b$.
- I want to find the product of $X=\{1, 2\}$ and $Y=\{1, 3\}$, looking at the definition, I think I need to collect all $i\in A$ such that we have $X\times Y \to X$ and $X\times Y \to Y$, there are two possibilities: $\{\},\{1\}$.
- Now I think that we need to check if for all $Z\in A$, we have the arrows: $Z\to X\times Y, Z \to X, Z \to Y$ for $X\times Y=\{\}$ and then for $X\times Y=\{1\}$.

The trouble I am facing is the following: The code I made takes each possibility for $X\times Y$ and highlights the following edges:

- $X\times Y \to X$
- $X\times Y \to Y$
- $Z\to X\times Y$
- $Z \to X$
- $Z \to Y$

For all $Z\in A$ if all them exist for some $Z$. It returns me the following graphs:

---

[image]

---

**Question:** I am a bit confused, what is the actual product here? Is it $\{\}$?Is it $\{1\}$? Is it both? I may be confusing something really silly but I am really lost here. I suspect $\{\}$ is not a product here but I don't know why.

Comment: Hint: $\{1\}$ is a subset of both $\{1,2\}$ and $\{1,3\}$, but not a subset of $\{\}$. What does that tell you about $\{\}$ being a product? On the other hand, any subset of both $\{1,2\}$ and $\{1,3\}$ is a subset of $\{1\}$. What does that tell you?

Comment: That's the most spectacular way to compute the intersection of two 2-element sets I've ever seen... May I suggest Rydeheard & Burstall's "Computational Category Theory"? I'm pretty sure they provide runnable code, and I'm also pretty sure that they use posets as examples.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Hahaha, I like to write code for things in math (when possible) and generate figures of them, I guess it helps me understand things better. Also, thanks for the book, by the title I'm pretty sure I'm gonna love it!

Comment: Side note: For the identity arrows to exist you need $a \subseteq b$ (instead of $a \subset b$).

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Many use $a\subset b$ to include the case $a=b$

Comment: @RedBanana Can you please share the Mathematica code / code you used for those diagrams, please? Thanks.

Comment: @JuliusHamilton Of course. [Here it is.](https://pastebin.com/ZEnvD7yB) It's a bit messy and I don't remember the code too well but in the variable `Obj` you set the objects in the category, the function `p[x,y]` is where you define the predicate so that it creates the arrows for the category and in `X` and `Y`, you define what objects you are computing the product. They are already in a convenient form: `X = Obj[[5]];` Where you can just change the numbers to obtain products between other objects in the category. If you need any help, contact me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case the product corresponds to the intersection.

Things you have:

1. $p_1 : \{1\}\rightarrow \{1,2\}$
2. $p_2 : \{1\}\rightarrow \{1,3\}$
3. $q_1 : \{\} \rightarrow \{1,2\}$
4. $q_2 : \{\} \rightarrow \{1,3\}$

Two candidates for a product with their respective projections. However $\{1\}$ has something stronger, and it's that for $\{\}$ and its projections $q_1$ and $q_2$, there is a unique map $\{\}\rightarrow\{1\}$ call it $f$ such that $q_1 = p_1\circ f$ and $q_2 = p_2\circ f$.

---

I think of it this way:

We say an object is a "candidate for a product" if it has the projections. (Formally we call it a "cone".)

Then, a product is a candidate for a product with "maximal information".

As you can see, we can "recover" $q_1$ from $p_1$ and $q_2$ from $p_2$ assuming $f$. So in a sense $p_1$ and $p_2$ "contain more information". And that's what's so fundamental about this definition of product.

---

Importantly, you don't have a map from $\{1\}$ to $\{\}$ that has the same effect. Else it could happen that both were products.

Comment: But assuming the product is $\{\}$ doesn't it also have this unique map? In this case: 

$$f = \{\}\to \{\} \\ q_1=p_1 = \{\}\to \{1,2\}\\ q_2=p_2 = \{\}\to \{1,3\}$$

The code I wrote gives me these five arrows (when I don't throw off the repetitions).

Comment: @RedBanana what you say is correct but not what we want, maybe I wasn't clear. The definition would be that $\{\}$ is a product of $\{1,2\}$ and $\{1,3\}$ if *for every* cone $x$, there is a morphism $x\rightarrow\{\}$ that factors the projections. In our case $\{1\}$ is a cone but fails to have such a mapping. (It doesn't have *any* mapping $\{1\}\rightarrow\{\}$ to begin with.)

Comment: I guess I understood it in my own crooked(?) way: First we collect all Z's that obey the definition, in this case: $\{\},\{1\}$, then we look for the arrows $\alpha$ **between the Z's** we found before?

Comment: @RedBanana For a product of $a$ and $b$ you can collect all cones (objects with a map to both $a$ and $b$) and then check for every arrow between every cone to see if there's an object with exactly one arrow that factors nicely through the projections of every other cone. It's really bad computationally in general, although for your example it is alright.

Comment: @RedBanana Instead, to make it algorithmically friendlier, you can consider a product as a function that takes cones as inputs and outputs arrows. So for instance in this case the product would be the function that when evaluated at $\{1\}$ gives the identity, and at $\{\}$ gives the arrow $\{\}\rightarrow\{1\}$. If you keep studying category theory you may see this written as $\Delta\dashv lim$.

Answer (score 3):

> Now I think that we need to check if for all $Z\in A$, we have the arrows: $Z\to X\times Y, Z \to X, Z \to Y$ for $X\times Y=\{\}$ and then for $X\times Y=\{1\}$.

I think this is where your confusion lies, since you don't have these arrows in logical order. We don't need universally arrows $Z \to X \times Y$, $Z \to X$, and $Z \to Y$. Instead, we have an arrow $Z \to X \times Y$ whenever there are arrows $Z \to X$, and $Z \to Y$ (subject to a uniqueness condition).

As you correctly surmise, $X \times Y$ in your example can only be either $\{\}$ or $\{1\}$ because those are the only objects with arrows to both $\{1, 2\}$ and $\{1, 3\}$. Let's prove that $\{\}$ is *not* the product.

For $\{\}$ to be the product, we need for every object $Z$ and every pair of arrows $f : Z \to X$ and $g : Z \to Y$, an arrow $\langle f, g \rangle : Z \to \{\}$. As pointed out before, if we have these arrows $f$ and $g$, $Z$ must be either $\{\}$ or $\{1\}$. Let's check with $Z = \{1\}$. $f$ and $g$ can only be one thing, so let's check that there is an arrow $Z \to \{\}$. But since $Z$ is $\{1\}$ and there is no arrow $\{1\} \to \{\}$, $\langle f, g \rangle$ can't exist. This proves that $\{\}$ cannot be the product.

**Spoilers below**

> You might try proving that in general, the product of two sets in your category are their intersection. Similarly, the coproduct is the union.

Comment: I guess I'm starting to see it: First we collect all $Z$'s that obey the definition, in this case: $\{\},\{1\}$, then we look for the unique arrow $\alpha$ **between the Z's** we found before?